# Missing model.config for model /path/to/your/workspace/meshes - ros2-foxy

Tags: gazebo, ros2, gazebo-model, ros-foxy

i am learning/working in ros2-foxy, and i am trying to implement a basic 4 wheel bot. If i define the wheels in shape(cylinder), the gazebo displays the wheel, But if i define the wheel in mesh tag, the gazebo didn't show and terminal shows error like this

```
[Err] [InsertModelWidget.cc:403] Missing model.config for model "/home/vasanth/.gazebo/models/baylands"
[spawn_entity.py-5] [INFO] [1693461888.305067820] [urdf_spawner]: Calling service /spawn_entity
[gazebo-4] [Err] [InsertModelWidget.cc:403] Missing model.config for model "/home/vasanth/ros2_ws/src/my_rover/.vscode"
[gazebo-4] [Err] [InsertModelWidget.cc:403] Missing model.config for model "/home/vasanth/ros2_ws/src/my_rover/config"
[gazebo-4] [Err] [InsertModelWidget.cc:403] Missing model.config for model "/home/vasanth/ros2_ws/src/my_rover/launch"
[gazebo-4] [Err] [InsertModelWidget.cc:403] Missing model.config for model "/home/vasanth/ros2_ws/src/my_rover/meshes"
[gazebo-4] [Err] [InsertModelWidget.cc:403] Missing model.config for model "/home/vasanth/ros2_ws/src/my_rover/my_rover"
[gazebo-4] [Err] [InsertModelWidget.cc:403] Missing model.config for model "/home/vasanth/ros2_ws/src/my_rover/resource"
[gazebo-4] [Err] [InsertModelWidget.cc:403] Missing model.config for model "/home/vasanth/ros2_ws/src/my_rover/test"
[gazebo-4] [Err] [InsertModelWidget.cc:403] Missing model.config for model "/home/vasanth/ros2_ws/src/my_rover/urdf"
[spawn_entity.py-5] [INFO] [1693461889.320005702] [urdf_spawner]: Spawn status: SpawnEntity: Successfully spawned entity [my_rover]
```

I added this rover.urdf file for your reference,i included one mesh file for one wheel to test whether it works or not.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
  <robot name="rover">


  <link name="chassis">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
          <box size="0.75 0.4 0.10"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="Orange">
          <color rgba="1.0 0.3 0.1 1.0"/>
      </material>
    </visual>
    <inertial>
            <mass value="5" />
            <inertia ixx="0.708305" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" 
            iyy="3.01029625" iyz="0" 
            izz="2.38532125" />
    </inertial>
    
    <collision>
      <geometry>
          <box size="0.75 0.4 0.10"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>

  <gazebo reference = "chassis">
      <material> Gazebo/Orange</material>
  </gazebo>


  <link name="front_right_wheel">
    <visual>
      
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="file://$(find my_rover)/meshes/right_tire.stl" scale="0.005 0.005 0.005"/>
          <!-- <cylinder radius="0.15" length="0.1"/> -->
      </geometry>
      <material name="Red">
          <color rgba="1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0"/>
      </material>
    </visual>

    <collision>  
      <geometry>
          <cylinder radius="0.033" length="0.018"/>
      </geometry>
      <contact_coefficients mu="1" kp="1e+13" kd="1.0"/>
    </collision>
    <inertial>
        <mass value="2.8498940e-02" />
        <inertia ixx="1.1175580e-05" ixy="-4.2369783e-11" ixz="-5.9381719e-09"
        iyy="1.1192413e-05" iyz="-1.4400107e-11"
        izz="2.0712558e-05" />       
    </inertial>
  </link>

  <joint name="front_right_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
    <origin xyz="0.2 0.24 0.0" rpy="-1.57 0.0 0.0"/> #-1.57
    <parent link="chassis"/>
    <child link="front_right_wheel"/>
    <axis xyz="0.0 0.0 1.0"/>
  </joint>

  <gazebo reference = "front_right_wheel">
      <material> Gazebo/Red</material>
  </gazebo>


  <link name="front_left_wheel">
    <visual>
      
      <geometry>
          <cylinder radius="0.15" length="0.1"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="Red">
          <color rgba="1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0"/>
      </material>
    </visual>

    <collision>
      <geometry>
          <cylinder radius="0.15" length="0.1"/>
      </geometry>
      <contact_coefficients mu="1" kp="1e+13" kd="1.0"/>
    </collision>
    <inertial>
        <mass value="2.8498940e-02" />
        <inertia ixx="1.1175580e-05" ixy="-4.2369783e-11" ixz="-5.9381719e-09"
        iyy="1.1192413e-05" iyz="-1.4400107e-11"
        izz="2.0712558e-05" />       
    </inertial>

  </link>

  <joint name="front_left_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
    <origin xyz="0.2 -0.24 0.0" rpy="-1.57 0.0 0.0"/>
    <parent link="chassis"/>
    <child link="front_left_wheel"/>
    <axis xyz="0.0 0.0 1.0"/>

  </joint>

  <gazebo reference = "front_left_wheel">
      <material> Gazebo/Red</material>
  </gazebo>


  <link name="back_right_wheel">
    <visual>
      
      <geometry>
          <cylinder radius="0.15" length="0.1"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="Red">
          <color rgba="1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0"/>
      </material>
    </visual>

    <collision>
      <geometry>
          <cylinder radius="0.15" length="0.1"/>
      </geometry>
      <contact_coefficients mu="1" kp="1e+13" kd="1.0"/>
    </collision>
    <inertial>
        <mass value="2.8498940e-02" />
        <inertia ixx="1.1175580e-05" ixy="-4.2369783e-11" ixz="-5.9381719e-09"
        iyy="1.1192413e-05" iyz="-1.4400107e-11"
        izz="2.0712558e-05" />       
    </inertial>

  </link>

  <joint name="back_right_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
    <origin xyz="-0.2 0.24 0.0" rpy="-1.57 0.0 0.0"/>
    <parent link="chassis"/>
    <child link="back_right_wheel"/>
    <axis xyz="0.0 0.0 1.0"/>

  </joint>

  <gazebo reference = "back_right_wheel">
      <material> Gazebo/Red</material>
  </gazebo>


  <link name="back_left_wheel">
    <visual>
      
      <geometry>
          <cylinder radius="0.15" length="0.1"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="Red">
          <color rgba="1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0"/>
      </material>
    </visual>

    <collision>
      <geometry>
          <cylinder radius="0.15" length="0.1"/>
      </geometry>
      <contact_coefficients mu="1" kp="1e+13" kd="1.0"/>
    </collision>
    <inertial>
        <mass value="2.8498940e-02" />
        <inertia ixx="1.1175580e-05" ixy="-4.2369783e-11" ixz="-5.9381719e-09"
        iyy="1.1192413e-05" iyz="-1.4400107e-11"
        izz="2.0712558e-05" />       
    </inertial>

  </link>

  <joint name="back_left_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
    <origin xyz="-0.2 -0.24 0.0" rpy="-1.57 0.0 0.0"/>
    <parent link="chassis"/>
    <child link="back_left_wheel"/>
    <axis xyz="0.0 0.0 1.0"/>

  </joint>

  <gazebo reference = "back_left_wheel">
      <material> Gazebo/Red</material>
  </gazebo>

  <link name="camera">
    <inertial>
            <mass value="0.5" />
            <inertia ixx="0.01" ixy="0.0" ixz="0" 
            iyy="0.01" iyz="0" izz="0.01" />
    </inertial>

    <visual>
      
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.010 0.05 0.05"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="blue">
        <color rgba="0 0 1 1"/>
      </material>
    </visual>

    <collision>
      <geometry>
          <box size="0.010 0.05 0.05"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>

  <joint name="camera_joint" type="fixed">
    <origin xyz="0.375 0.0 0.0" rpy="0 0.0 3.14"/>
    <parent link="chassis"/>
    <child link="camera"/>
  </joint>

  <gazebo reference = "camera">
      <material> Gazebo/Blue</material>
  </gazebo>

  <link name="lidar_mount">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.1 0.1 0.1" />
      </geometry>
      <material name="Black">
        <color rgba="0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0"/>
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.1 0.1 0.1" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  
  <joint name="lidar_mount_joint" type="fixed">
    <origin xyz="0.2 0.0 0.10" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
    <parent link="chassis"/>
    <child link="lidar_mount"/>
  </joint>

  <gazebo reference = "lidar_mount">
      <material> Gazebo/Black</material>
  </gazebo>
  
  <link name="lidar">
    <inertial>
            <mass value="0.5" />
            <inertia ixx="0.01" ixy="0.0" ixz="0" 
            iyy="0.01" iyz="0" izz="0.01" />
    </inertial>

    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder radius="0.1" length="0.1"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="red">
        <color rgba="1 0 0  1"/>
      </material>
    </visual>

    <collision>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder radius="0.1" length="0.1"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>

  <joint name="lidar_joint" type="fixed">
    <origin xyz="0.0 0 0.10" rpy="0 0.0 0.0"/>
    <parent link="lidar_mount"/>
    <child link="lidar"/>
  </joint>

  <gazebo reference = "lidar">
      <material> Gazebo/Red</material>
  </gazebo>
</robot>
```

this is the launch file

```
import os
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch.actions import ExecuteProcess

def generate_launch_description():
    package_dir = get_package_share_directory('my_rover')
    urdf = os.path.join(package_dir,'rover.urdf')
    rviz_config_file=os.path.join(package_dir,'config.rviz')

    return LaunchDescription([
        Node(
            package='robot_state_publisher',
            executable='robot_state_publisher',
            name='robot_state_publisher',
            output='screen',
            arguments=[urdf]),
        Node(
            package='joint_state_publisher_gui',
            executable='joint_state_publisher_gui',
            name='joint_state_publisher_gui',
            arguments=[urdf]),

        Node(
        package='rviz2',
        executable='rviz2',
        name='rviz2',
        arguments=['-d',rviz_config_file],
        output='screen'),
        
#Gazebo parameters for simulation
        ExecuteProcess(
            cmd = ['gazebo', '--verbose', '-s', 'libgazebo_ros_factory.so'],
            output = 'screen'),

        Node(
            package= 'gazebo_ros',
            executable= 'spawn_entity.py',
            name = 'urdf_spawner',
            output = 'screen',
            arguments = ["-topic", "/robot_description", "-entity", "my_rover"])     
    ])
```

How can i resolve this issue?